# Angular Chart not rendering but dev tools says no errors

Tags: angularjs, charts, angular-material, angular-chart

I am using Angular and Material Design.
When I add an Angular Chart it does not render on the page but the dev tools of chrome is not showing any errors.  What could I have done wrong?

I have setup a plunker for this [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/7chdV3uXCkRU0riHRBk8?p=preview)

To have an idea of my code pls see snippet below

```
 <div role="tabpanel"
               id="tab1-content"
               aria-labelledby="tab1"
               ng-switch-when="0"
               md-swipe-left="next()"
               md-swipe-right="previous()"
               layout="row" layout-align="center center">
              <md-card flex-gt-sm="90" flex-gt-md="80">
                <md-card-content>
                  <h2>Profile / Utilization</h2>

                  <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" data="data"
                    labels="labels"></canvas> 

                  <md-list>


                  </md-list>
                </md-card-content>
              </md-card>
          </div>
```

index.js

```
 var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMdIcons','chart.js']);

 app.controller("DoughnutCtrl", function ($scope) {
 $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];      
 $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];});
```

Comment: Could you setup jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: Is the tab that hosts the chart initially hidden? I seem to remember an issue with angular charts not rendering when they are initially not visible on the page.

Comment: Hi guys I have setup a plunker for my code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7chdV3uXCkRU0riHRBk8?p=preview)

Comment: Why do you have 3 <head> tags and 3 <body> tags?  That cant be good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because nowhere do you bind "DoughnutController" to your view..

I moved this block to "AppCtrl" and it works..

```
$scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
$scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zkXYb5sHmwRUQQPmsdbq?p=preview

(I also got rid of your 3 `<head>` tags and 3 `<body>` tags)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to specify the controller for the chart.  So

```
<md-card-content ng-controller="DoughnutCtrl">
```

As it stands, your code's context is bound to `AppCtrl` which doesn't contain the chart data.

Comment: I did what you said
    <md-card-content ng-controller="DoughnutCtrl">
still not working though.  But theoreticall it is the more correct answer because I want to create many charts with individual controllers.  How do I do this?  Can you check my Plunker from my question or modify this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zkXYb5sHmwRUQQPmsdbq?p=preview)

Comment: Here is the modified [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r8KFKj7r64IwcDqtrgYB?p=preview).

Comment: All I did was remove the chart data properties from AppCtrl and then add the controller data attribute as described above.  Works for me in Chrome and Edge.  Splitting out data and logic into separate controllers for each   UI component is the right way to go (as opposed to having all the data and logic on a single controller).